# Is the exact endianness of an Ethernet Frame start with LSbit of Octet (MSByte)?

Tags: ethernet

Following up this question: [Confusions regarding byte and bit ordering of Ethernet Frame](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/59874/confusions-regarding-byte-and-bit-ordering-of-ethernet-frame)

Just so I get the understanding correct, if I have a Destination address of the way we usually read MSByte/MSbit:

| 47 | 46 | 45 | 44 | 43 | 42 | 41 | 40 | 39 | 38 | 37 | 36 | 35 | 34 | 33 | 32 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | ... |

Would my MSByte octet be bits 47 to 40? If so, that leads me to believe I should be transmitting this: `01111111 00010011` from left to right order.

Is this correct? So the octet itself doesn't move positions regardless whether we are reading it as humans or actually transmitting it on the wire?

I am sorta inferring the "most significant octet" is the order we read hex (left to right).

So for payload of 42 octets, my Length field consists of MSOctet `0x00` and LSOctet `0x2A`? For payload of 1500 octets (`0x05 0xDC`), my MS-Octet is `0x05` and transmission bits of `1010 0000 0011 1011` from left to right?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. It's all in the linked question, mate. Note that the *Length/Ethertype* field is the Ethertype field for most frame formats.

Comment: @Zac67 the reason why I am asking with an example here is because I want to make sure "most significant octet" doesn't mean something different in the 802.3 spec. And I don't see many examples online that express the endianness in bits exactly. My apologies.

Comment: The most reliable source is [IEEE 802.3](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/browse/standards/get-program/page/series?id=68), by definition.